# How can I put an XML message (encoding ISO-8859-2) manual in a local queue in IBM Websphere MQ?

Tags: ibm-mq

My problem is: there is an application, that wants from me XML messages with ISO-8859-2 encoding. Currently I use IBM MQ Explorer 9.0, and there are two queues in a queue manager. Either of them use I to put the XML message manual:copy XML->select queue->right click->put test message->paste the XML in the inputfield->Put.
(The other one is the queue, where the response messages are).
When I put an XML message with these ISO-8859-2 encoding, the "ő" and "ű" characters change to another characters. Actually, the application, that reads the XML messages from this queue, uses ISO-8859-2 encoding, and it gets this message with the bad "ő", "ű" characters (õ, û).
The message doesnt pass between queue managers. I dont know the application, that the message reads from the queue. They said, they want the XML messages with ISO-8859-2 encoding.
When I put the message, and click to "browse messages" by the queue, and I see the message properties, the 'character set id' is 1208. I think, it must be 912. Isn't it the problem? How can I change it?

This is the message data properties, that I put to the queue:
 [image: This is the message data properties, that I put to the queue]

And we get the message with these properties:
[image: And we get the message with these properties]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using MQGMO_CONVERT on your MQGET?  Are you setting CodedCharSetId field of MQMD on your MQPUT?  What is the default code page of the queue manager?  Are you specifying MQFMT_STRING in the Format field of the MQMD?

Comment: I believe you are stating the actual data you are putting to the queue is ISO-8859-2.  How are you putting this to the queue and what API are you using to put to the queue.  How are you getting the data from the queue and what API are you using to get from the queue.  Does the message pass between queue managers, if so does the sender channel have `CONVERT(YES)` set?  Please don't put a lot of data in comments, please click "edit" under your question and add more details.

Comment: With MQ Explorer the "put test message" is just for sending small test messages and there is little to no control over things like CCSID of the message put.  MQ Explorer itself is an application that uses IBM MQ classes for Java API to access MQ and the default CCSID for Java is 1208.  You should look at other tools to put messages like RFHUtil, Capitalware's [MQ Visual Edit](https://www.capitalware.com/mqve_overview.html), or MQGem Software's [MQEdit](http://mqgem.com/mqedit.html) if you want something off the shelf.